# Audio (mp3) file issue, file is not played at number of button press

Tags: iphone, ios

I have set music file on button click in the **memory game** application.

Music is properly played, for some time but after the number of the buttons click looses the sound effect from the applcation.

```
-(void)setButtons_AsPerTheMatrixSelection
{
    for ( i = 0 ; i < cv ; ++i )
    {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < ch ; ++j )
        {
            btnMatrix = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10+pw*j, 51+ph*i, width, height)] autorelease];
            btnMatrix.tag = i*ch+j;
            btnMatrix.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
            bulImageStatus = FALSE;
            [btnMatrix addTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [btnMatrix setImage:imgDefaultBG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [viewWithButtons addSubview:btnMatrix];

            [arrButton addObject:btnMatrix];
        }
    }
}    

-(void)changeImage:(id)sender
{
    NSString *musicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ding" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (musicPath) 
        TapSoud = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath] error:nil];

    [TapSoud setDelegate:self];
    [TapSoud prepareToPlay];
    [TapSoud play];
}
```

This is working perfectly for number of presses but after certain click i am not able to play this button click tone.

what can be the issue & how can be solved this issue.

Is there any other way to play audio file?

Please suggest the appropriate solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello... @WrightsCS... can you suggest me how can i format code by default, is there any shortcut keys to format whole code...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVAudioPlayer is alloced over and over but never released.

try this.

```
-(void)changeImage:(id)sender
{
    NSString *musicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ding" ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (musicPath) {
        if(TapSoud){ // TapSound ? 
             [TapSoud release];
              TapSoud = nil;
        }
        TapSoud = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL 
fileURLWithPath:musicPath] error:nil];
}

[TapSoud setDelegate:self];
[TapSoud prepareToPlay];
[TapSoud play];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use same AVAudioPlayer refrence every time u play:

```
-(void)changeImage:(id)sender
{
  NSString *musicPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ding" ofType:@"mp3"];
  if (musicPath) {
    if(!TapSoud){ // check TapSound has reference
         TapSoud = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath] error:nil];
         [TapSoud setDelegate:self]
    }
    else
    {
        NSNumber *time = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0];
        //NSTimeInterval interval = [time doubleValue];
       [TapSoud playAtTime:[time doubleValue];// Smae Sound played at time 0:00
    }

  }
 }
```